# Build elements in jQuery and add to dom

Tags: jquery

I am trying to build a ul list in jQuery, however it seems to be only creating the ul element, and not the li??

```
var list = $('<ul></ul>').append($("<li/>").addClass('test').text('hello'));
```

Seems simple enough, but not sure why it won't work??

Comment: You're never appending it to the DOM

Comment: Works fine if you actually append it: http://jsfiddle.net/xeARY/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var list = $('<ul></ul>').append($("<li/>").addClass('test').text('hello'));

$('body').append(list);
```

here is the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/JH3ef/

Answer (score 0):

Works for me. See http://jsbin.com/owovay/edit#javascript,html

Are you adding the list to the page?

Answer (score 0):

try to actually append the new created ul element to the body:

```
 var list = $('<ul></ul>').append($("<li/>").addClass('test').text('hello')).appendTo('body');
```

Answer (score 0):

Add a call to `.appendTo()` at the end to get your UL in the DOM.

```
var list = $('<ul></ul>').append($("<li/>").addClass('test').text('hello')).appendTo("body");
```